# how do you check to see if any conda environment is active with a flag

Tags: python, conda

How can I tell if any conda environment is active with a flag?

i.e. when I try to run

```sh
conda deactivate && conda env list
```

or when I run

```sh
conda activate && conda env list
```

they both output the same thing

```sh
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/name/opt/miniconda3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer myself.  There is a `CONDA_SHLVL` environment variable.

```sh
[[ $CONDA_SHLVL == 1 ]] && echo "conda environment is active"
```

Another option would be to run

`conda info` but the output must be parsed

when a conda env is not active it will display

```
william‣ wmbp‣ ~ % conda info                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

     active environment : None
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mac OS, you can also use `conda env list` which will show all available environments with an asterisk next to the currently active one.

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                    /Users/yourname/miniconda3
dataEnv              *  /Users/yourname/miniconda3/envs/dataEnv
webParsing              /Users/yourname/miniconda3/envs/webParsing
```

Comment: This does not clearly show when there is no conda env active, i.e. when `conda deactivate` is run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In Mac OS using Zsh at least the base env will be marked as active if no other env has been activated. Haven't tested how this looks in other operating systems or shells.